# What happens to the gains or losses made on the non-vested portion of a 401k after you leave your job?

Tags: 401k, contribution, employer-match, vesting

If you leave a company that matched 401k contributions before the vesting schedule is complete, the non-vested money is returned to the employer.  I'm curious what happens to the gains/losses on the non-vested money.

If your contributions have vested 80% upon your departure, the employer is returned 20%.  Is it exactly 20% of their contribution (i.e., the employee keeps the gains/losses from the non-vested money) or is it 20% of the employer-contributed balance in the account (i.e., the employer keeps the gains/losses from the non-vested money?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my quarterly statement and the 401K plan website I can see the vesting for various categories.

- A: My contribution (100% vested)
- B: My dividends (100% vested)
- C: Company Match (60% vested)
- D: Employer Contribution Dividends (100% vested)

They total all these up and report the total balance and the vested balance.

If I do the math I discover that the vested balance is equal to A + B + D + (60% of C)

For my company at least, if I was to leave now I would get 60% of the Company match, which does include significant gains.

This document for the [Department of Labor](http://www.dol.gov/ebsa/publications/wyskapr.html) discuss many aspects of 401K plans including vesting.

> In a defined contribution plan such as a 401(k) plan, you are always
>   100 percent vested in your own contributions to a plan, and in any
>   subsequent earnings from your contributions. However, in most defined
>   contribution plans you may have to work several years before you are
>   vested in the employer’s matching contributions. (There are
>   exceptions, such as the SIMPLE 401(k) and safe harbor 401(k), in which
>   you are immediately vested in all required employer contributions. You
>   also vest immediately in the SIMPLE IRA and the SEP.)
>
> Currently, employers have a choice of two different vesting schedules
>   for employer matching 401(k) contributions, which are shown in Table
>   2. Your employer may use a schedule in which employees are 100 percent vested in employer contributions after 3 years of service (cliff
>   vesting). Under graduated vesting, an employee must be at least 20
>   percent vested after 2 years, 40 percent after 3 years, 60 percent
>   after 4 years, 80 percent after 5 years, and 100 percent after 6
>   years. If your automatic enrollment 401(k) plan requires employer
>   contributions, you vest in those contributions after 2 years.
>   Automatic enrollment 401(k) plans with optional matching contributions
>   follow one of the vesting schedules noted above.

Comment: Are there laws about what happens to the 40% of the match that you leave behind?  Does it just go back to the employer?  Do they have to keep it in a 401(k) pool for other employee matching?

Comment: @dg99 it goes back to the employer to do as they please. If accounting-wise it make sense to shift the money to another account instead of depositing new money there - they may do it, but what is it to you?